# Android MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW not working

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm using a webView to display a webpage that uses https but after some payment process it reloads to my webpage that is using http. In this case the message is:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://paymentservice.com' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint 'http://myapi.com/finish_payment'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.

This is the setup for the WebView (I have been playing with setMixedContentMode with any luck):

```
WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36");
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
 Log.v(TAG, "MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW");
 webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );
}
webView.loadData(url, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Did you solve this yet?

Comment: better to use a free SSL service like Cloudflare to serve your page

Comment: yes, basically this warning won't stop your program to keep running. My problem was that I needed to listen a response from javascript and I was implementing wrongly that feature